# Dynamic programming m*n grid shortest sumpath

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am learning some algos and DS, and came across a DP problem. Looking for some hints. Here is the statement:

> Given a  mxn grid filled with non-negative numbers, find a path from top left to bottom right which minimizes the sum of all numbers along its path.
>
> **Note**: You can only move either down or right at any point in time.

**Hints** only please!

I've thought of some things but they just don't work. It doesnt make sense because my initial idea was,

Memoize with dp[i][j] where dp[i][j] is the minimum path sum for an i*j grid. This doesn't make sense because I am for example not sure how to get do[i + 1][j + 1] from this.

Is the idea correct. Can you suggest something?

Comment: Google for A* (A star)

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the corner cells, i.e. `dp[0][j]` and `dp[i][0]`. Then for any `dp[i][j]`, the cost of traversing till that path will be `val[i][j] + min(dp[i-1][j-1], dp[i-1][j], dp[i][j-1])`.

`dp[row][col]` should have the cost of minimum path. You can also backtrack using `dp[][]` and find the minimum cost path as well.

Good luck.